# Installing Android Emulator In Android Studio with zip files

Tags: android-emulator

I wasn't able to install an emulator to my android studio installation. So, I copied this link from the studio and downloaded the zip file. Now I need help on how to manually install it using the zip files I downloaded.

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/x86_64-25_r03.zip

Comment: What are the issues you have experienced with Android Studio, exactly? What steps did you attempt? What documentation did you read and follow?

Comment: I was trying to add an emulator to the studio and it would always give errors and it was displaying the link from which it was downloading the files....So I took the link and manually downloaded the zip file..But now how to make it work with the studio...

Comment: Ok thanks very much I solved it myself...Only the downloaded files need to be put in the sdk folder and then we create the emulator, it detects the dowloaded image

Comment: You may post an answer to your question and mark it as accepted so that others would know that such a question has a working solution. Otherwise you may delete your question if you think that it does not provide any benefit to general audience (that way you will remove the downvotes as well, if I am not mistaken).

Comment: The method given by @Faizan worked for me to the T. I have used a download manager to get the zip file and extracted it in the correct folder. When creating the virtual device just make sure you refresh the list of where system images are listed in the create new device window. Don't click on download again.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had a problem downloading the Emulator(Image files) from the android studio. So when you try to run your app witout an emulator. It asks for an option to create a new emulator wherin it'll download the required files. It use to download 60-70% and give error. So I used the link in the download dialogbox, and manually downloaded the zip file. Now that zip file needs to be extracted and has to be pasted in the sdk folder.

sdk/system-images/android-(api level)/(extracted folder)

Note:This is my first thread so You might suggest some improvements

Comment: you've to replace your api level and the extracted folder in the respected brackets

Answer (score 6):

I think francis-bacon solution is right (I don't see why you would install the emulator in a system image folder as faizann-gagan wrote) but it is partial: you may have noticed that many components of the SDK has a **package.xml** file. Platforms, docs, tools... Without this file, the SDK manager will show the component as missing as long as it is not present.

Problem is, when you unzip the emulator package, you won't find a package.xml. (I guess it is added by the SDK manager upon installation completion)

I could get a copy of this file from a backup and modified the version number to match the one in source.properties (at the time of writing, 29.0.11)
An old package.xml can be found at https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/emulator/package.xml also.

Confirmed working on Mac OS High Sierra and Windows 8.1

Comment: update: the package.xml file is actually created by Android Studio when one starts the SDK manager. I ran into cases where this xml file was not created so I cheated by creating it from another valid one.

Answer (score 2):

When I launch the avd, I got the following error:

> Emulator: Could not launch
>   '/Users/gongzelong/Downloads/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386':
>   No such file or directory

I entered SDK-> Android Emulator in Android studio, and try to download Android Emulator.

But I got the following error when downloading it.

> To install:
>    - Android Emulator (emulator) Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 27.3.9)". Downloading
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-4899998.zip
>   An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Cannot
>   download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-4899998.zip':
>   /var/folders/gf/hgd91n6x5v73ct9dvhr379500000gn/T/PackageOperation02/emulator-darwin-4899998.zip
>   (No such file or directory) , response: 200 OK. "Install Android
>   Emulator (revision: 27.3.9)" failed. Failed packages:
>    - Android Emulator (emulator)

Here is how I solve the problem.

I downloaded the file https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-4899998.zip from Chrome and unzip the zip and got the directory 'emulator'

[image: zip and extracted directory emulater]

Then I copy the emulator under sdk

[image: location in location]

And then launch the AVD in Android studio, and everything works well.

Comment: In China .  I try copy the .zip file to sdk folder , and cancel proxy setting , reinstall . Then everything is ok.

Comment: this did not work for me, since AVD still couldn't recognize it, and when clicking download emulator, the unzipped `emulator` folder is deleted and a new empty one is then created

Answer (score 0):

So I faced almost similar error today but it was about updating the emulator itself. Cause was the folder Android tried to download the file needed root permissions to access it. So here is what I did:

1. Downloaded the file in the directory accessible `curl https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-4899998.zip -o emulator-darwin-4899998.zip`
2. Create the path as root user `sudo mkdir -p /var/folders/8t/kf42z0w94278zwm6x_wzll7c0000gp/T/PackageOperation03/`
3. Make it writable by everyone `sudo chmod -Rfv 777 /var/folders/8t/kf42z0w94278zwm6x_wzll7c0000gp/T/PackageOperation03/
   /var/folders/8t/kf42z0w94278zwm6x_wzll7c0000gp/T/PackageOperation03/`
4. Move the downloaded file to the path `mv emulator-darwin-4899998.zip /var/folders/8t/kf42z0w94278zwm6x_wzll7c0000gp/T/PackageOperation03/`
5. Finally run Android Studio update check and let it update. It will check existing file and use that one to update instead of re-downloading

Answer (score 0):

The Answer works as well, if you have only 4Gig of swap memory available and AVD unzips into [/tmp] untill it's full, leaving it that way after throwing an out of disk space error.

So, one need to have at least (3.2+0.75) ~= 4Gig of *real* free virtual memory to install via AVD.

I stress this only, because I did a distro upgrade after that (...), and it rendered the system unbootable.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had the same error of the emulator failing to install from android studio. I tried downloading the zip and extract it in the SDK as per the top solutions It also didnt work. I just fixed it by **allowing android studio through windows firewall and controlled folder access** now it downloaded successfully in android studio

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Android Studio 3.5.3, Windows 10. After emulator update 29.3.4, I also got a similar error to above when trying to install emulators (I tried Pixel 3 and 2):

```
*Packages to install: 
    - Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86_64)
    Preparing "Install Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (revision: 8)".
    Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/x86_64-28_r08.zip
    An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/x86_64-28_r08.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK.
    "Install Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (revision: 8)" failed.
    Failed packages:
    Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86_64)*
```

Running Android Studio as Administrator solved the problem for me.