# how to offline install emulator (virtual device) in android studio?

Tags: android, emulation

I am new to Android Studio and I need some help:

How can I install the emulator (virtual device) in Android Studio offline?
The Android Studio downloading process is very slow and it never finishes. See this [screenshot of download stuck.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtQrB.png)

So what should I do?!
Help, please.

Comment: https://imgur.com/vSRM07j

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Android Emulator In Android Studio with zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311344/installing-android-emulator-in-android-studio-with-zip-files)

Answer (score -2):

You can use your android device itself,
Just go to setting and enable developer option and select usb debugging. And when you click run button it will automatically detect your device connected with machine via USB.

Answer (score -3):

you can use genymotion or find and insrall android image with virtual machine(virtualbox if i remember the nsme correctly)